# If $\phi\in\mathsf{Aut}(G)$ fixes conjugacy classes and $G$ is finite then do we have $\phi\in\mathsf{Inn}(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

If a group automorphism $\phi:G\to G$ is an inner automorphism then it fixes conjugacy classes in the sense that $\phi(C)=C$ for every conjugacy class $C$.

When I encountered this for the first time (long ago) I wondered whether the converse of this might be true. Only since short I am wiser because someone provided me a nice counterexample. It concerned the permutation group on the set of positive integers.

However he could not give me (yet) a finite group as counterexample.

This gave birth to my question:

> If $\phi:G\to G$ is an automorphism that fixes conjugacy classes and moreover group $G$ is finite then can we conclude that $\phi$ is an inner automorphism?

Thank you for taking notice and sorry on forehand if it is a duplicate.

Comment: There's a finite example [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class-preserving_not_implies_inner)

Comment: @MatthewTowers That's a quick response. Thank you very much Matthew.

Comment: No, we haven't in general that result. See e.g. here for a historical counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838188/inner-automorphism-group-as-the-kernel-of-a-homomorphism/3838521?noredirect=1#comment7918217_3838521

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312586

Comment: @Devo Indeed it does. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

It is true for finite simple groups. This is a result of Walter Feit and Gary Seitz (1984). Seitz communicated this to me in a letter, but it was formally published afterwards. I needed the result for classifying finite groups whose complex irreducible characters are all primitive, see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250752370_On_finite_groups_all_of_whose_irreducible_complex_characters_are_primitive) (in particular $(6.1)$).

**Article**: the result of Feit and Seitz appeared in *On finite rational groups and related topics*, [Illinois Jour. of Math.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-33/issue-1/On-finite-rational-groups-and-related-topics/10.1215/ijm/1255988808.full), vol. 33 (1989), pages 103-131. It needs the CFSG.

Comment: Thank you for this extra result, Nicky. I had a look at your profile and was pleasantly surprised. In "de zeventiger jaren" I studied at UvA. Moreover every week I go to church in Amstelveen.

Comment: Leuk Henk! Wellicht dat we samen in de collegebanken hebben gezeten dan ...